# Express JS - deleting entry from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am using Express.js to build a small application. I have successfully implement the feature that allows me to add new entries to the database.

I am currently trying to delete an entry from a mysql db when a user clicks on a button. This is the code that gets executed:

```
client.query('DELETE FROM humans WHERE id= ?', [req.params.id], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        res.redirect('/humans');
```

I know that the code executes properly because I get redirected to the correct page. Still, my entry is still in the database.

Comment: Obvious question is the `id` being passed set/correct?

Comment: @WiredPrairie - yes; I have a hidden input field that has the value of the id and the name attribute set to id, so that when I post that form it will get passed; when I inspect the page it is visible and the value is correct

Comment: Looks like the answer to my question was "sort of" given what you accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deducing from the comments to your question I guess that you're sending the id from a form using a POST request. To find post params in req.body (if you're using the express.bodyParser middleware). Thus:

```
client.query('DELETE FROM humans WHERE id= ?', [req.body.id], function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }

  res.redirect('/humans');
});
```

If you're sending a GET request the param would be find in req.query.

Comment: It works perfectly now! From what you just explained, I get it that whenever I send a POST request, I can no longer access the parameters using req.params. and I am bound to using req.body.?

Comment: No, you could never access form data through req.params. Form data us usually sent as a url-encoded string, either in the body (for POSTs) or in the query string (for GETs). Consider `/foo/bar` vs `/foo?value=bar`. The first request could be handled by a route like `/foo/:value` in express and the param would be found at `req.params.value`. The second request however sends the value in the query string, and thus the value is found in `req.query.value`.

Comment: (of course the same reasoning applies to POSTs and req.body, but it's harder to demonstrate in this short format since the body not part of the url)